# How to get the rect of a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios6, uicollectionview

`UITableView` has the method `rectForRowAtIndexPath:`, but this does not exist in UICollectionView. I'm looking for a nice clean way to grab a cell's bounding rectangle, perhaps one that I could add as a category on `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is the following:

**Objective-C**

```c
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**Swift**

```swift
let attributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
```

Then you can access the location through either `attributes.frame` or `attributes.center`

Comment: This will give the absolute position of the cell related to the superview

`CGRect cellFrameInSuperview = [self.collectionView convertRect:attributes.frame toView:[self.collectionView superview]];`

Answer (score 54):

Only two lines of code is required to get perfect frame :

**Objective-C**

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes * theAttributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

CGRect cellFrameInSuperview = [collectionView convertRect:theAttributes.frame toView:[collectionView superview]];
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
let theAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
let cellFrameInSuperview = collectionView.convert(theAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
```

Answer (score 18):

in swift 3

```
 let theAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
 let cellFrameInSuperview:CGRect!  = collectionView.convert(theAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
```

Answer (score 9):

in swift you can just do:

```
//for any cell in collectionView
let rect = self.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(clIndexPath).frame

//if you only need for visible cells
let rect = cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.frame
```

Answer (score -2):

How about

```
-(CGRect)rectForCellatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        return CGRectZero;
    }

    return cell.frame;

}
```

as a category on `UICollectionView`?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UICollectionView (CellFrame)

-(CGRect)rectForCellatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end


#import "UICollectionView+CellFrame.h"

@implementation UICollectionView (CellFrame)

-(CGRect)rectForCellatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        return CGRectZero;
    }

    return cell.frame;

}

@end
```

Comment: This works, but gives the cell's frame as it is within its own view hierarchy (meaning every cell will have an origin of {0,0}). I need to know what the rect is within the table view.

Comment: Use `UIView`'s `convertRect:toView:` method to convert the rect relative to the collection view.

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath path only returns a value for visible cells. If the cell at the indexPath is off screen it returns nil.

Comment: Your solution is fine; however, I'd amend it with the convertRect:toView: method as suggested. That's for two reasons: 1) that's the only reason for getting a cell's rect in this way; 2) this is essential part of peek-and-pop functionality. That it only works for visible cells is a lame criticism from per reason #2; you will never need the rect of an offscreen cell, which is why the means to do it is not provided by any other framework. I upvoted your answer, and I intend to employ it in my current project today.

Comment: @JamesBush, I disagree with your comment. Firstly, I would not amend it with the `convertRect:toView:` method as it's too specific and not everyone needs it. Or maybe someone needs to convert it to the `superview of the `superview` of the collection view, but you're essentially saying to assume one's view hierarchy. Secondly, you also assume people's use cases. I, for example, actually do need the rect of an off-screen cell.